# How can I initialize a date vector?

Tags: datetime, initialization, julia

I have to use Julia for a problem set for class. I've never used it before and I've only ever really used Matlab/Stata.

I want to initialize an empty date vector, so that I can store values in it in a for loop. The for loop will have a lot of if statements that will change how I input into the date vector. It'd be something like this:

```
using Dates

date = vector(N,1) # Need help with this line
for i in 1:N
    if stuff1
        date[i] = blah1
    elseif stuff2
        date[i] = blah2
    else
        date[i] = blah3
    end
end
```

Answer (score 3):

Use:

```
julia> N = 5
5

julia> date = Vector{Date}(undef, N)
5-element Vector{Date}:
 56207879210758--12056695473012767-3689348814741910322
 97580475146329-6028347736506381-7378697629483820659
 -99964444404694-24113390946025549-7378697629483820668
 -54150401430865--30141738682531934-3689348814741910309
 0001-02-07
```

for an uninitialized vector, or:

```
julia> fill(Date(2022, 03, 18), N)
5-element Vector{Date}:
 2022-03-18
 2022-03-18
 2022-03-18
 2022-03-18
 2022-03-18
```

to initially fill it with some default value.